# Modify the size and the type of the font

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm a beginner in Pyqt and I made the main form but I don't know how to modify the size and the type of the font in the Qlabel?

```
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.center()
    self.setWindowTitle('GBLtda Database')
    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
    self.resize(1028, 720)
    label = QtGui.QLabel('GB DATABASE', self)
    label.move(15, 10)
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('db.png'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using stylesheets:

```
#for the whole widget   
self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 30pt Comic Sans MS}")
#Just for this label
label.setStyleSheet("font: 30pt Comic Sans MS")
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Do you know how to put this label in bold?

Comment: @MargaritaGonzalez I think you just have to add something like `font: bold 30pt Comic Sans MS`

Comment: how to set style sheet for QListView

Comment: Hey @M4rtini What if i have a custom font downloaded? How to add it to stylesheet? Will it work?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to set the font using `setFont(QFont)` method.

```
label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it inherits from QWidget I guess you should be able to apply a stylesheet via member .setStyleSheet?

i.e.:
http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples/

Comment: If you read the question you'd see that the OP is *already* calling the `setStyleSheet` method. However he doesn't seem to know *what* to put into the style sheet.